# How to avoid a gradle build error when a dependency does not exist, compile should be ok anyway

Tags: java, gradle, gradle-plugin, artifact

How can I avoid a build error during dependency resolution in a Java Gradle plugin when programmatically adding a dependency whose name is calculated based on certain criteria?
I need to handle cases where the dependency may not exist in my artifact repository, with its version being retrieved from a Maven BOM.
Even if the dependency does not exist, I still want my build to proceed without errors.
Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

I tried to resolve my dependency using a detachedConfiguration and catching any Exception on the resolve() method so that I could add it to the exclusions of the respective configurations.
This solution works, but I had to define the version of the dependency, whereas, as mentioned earlier, the version is defined by the Maven BOM.

Comment: show the error and you're pom file please

Comment: Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':compileClasspath'.
   > Could not find org.mdambrosio:devtools-error:1.0.0.
     Required by:
         project :

This dependency is added by my custom gradle plugin.

Comment: show the error please and pom file , bemuse I want to see , what dependency have the pom file

Comment: @AmerAlMunajjed what's the purpose of having POM file? Question is: how to make  a build successful also when a dependency is not found on maven.